# How to create a function with output parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am rewriting code from pl/sql to tsql and want to create a function with output parameters in tsql like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [CALC_EXZ].[CALC_AZ_RESIST_FULL]
(
    @i_ukz_key        NUMERIC(20),
    @c_err_message    VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
    @c_recommendation VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
)
RETURNS NUMERIC(20,6) 
AS 

BEGIN
DECLARE @result NUMERIC(20,6)


    EXECUTE [DB_LIB].[CALC_EXZ].[CALC_AZ_RESIST_FULL]
    @i_ukz_key, 
    @c_err_message    OUTPUT, 
    @c_recommendation OUTPUT, 
    @result           OUTPUT; 

    IF @result=-1 AND @c_err_message IS NULL 
    SET @result=NULL;   

    RETURN @result
END
```

but i get errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `OUTPUT` parameters with a user defined function (UDF).  By definition a scalar function just returns one scalar value.

You have two options:

1 - Make this a stored procedure using `OUTPUT` parameters.
2 - Use a table valued function (TVF) that returns a table containing multiple rows